# SQL Server created table runs slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a temp table called `#PILOTTERR`. There are over 40,000 records that I need to insert into this table. This takes about 10 min to execute. Is there a way I can make this faster?

```
CREATE TABLE #PILOTTERR 
(
     Zip TEXT, 
     Office CHAR(4), 
     Branch NVARCHAR(33), 
     District NVARCHAR(37), 
     Region NVARCHAR(26), 
     SE_Territory NVARCHAR(42), 
     ISE_Territory NVARCHAR(43)
);

INSERT INTO #PILOTTERR 
VALUES ('00544','NY04','Long Island','New York-Long Island','US Northeast','SE-New York/Long Island-A','ISE-New York/Long Island-D')

INSERT INTO #PILOTTERR 
VALUES ('01001','MA01','North Boston','North Boston','US Northeast','SE-North Boston-C','ISE-North Boston-B')
    etc....
```

Comment: why are you using TEXT datatype for Zip. it seems a bit of overkill?

Comment: I didn't want the data to be confused as anything but text.  Does the text data type usually take longer to run?

Comment: TEXT is a depricated data type. so I would avoid using it, same goes with IMAGE.

Comment: may I ask how you are getting your records? As in what format csv, etc...

Comment: I am copying and pasting from a micrsoft excel file.

Comment: that's way too time consuming, try using import task

Comment: Here is where you can find out more about it https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
CREATE TABLE #PILOTTERR (
                    Zip NVARCHAR(10), 
                    Office CHAR(4), 
                    Branch NVARCHAR(33), 
                    District NVARCHAR(37), 
                    Region NVARCHAR(26), 
                    SE_Territory NVARCHAR(42), 
                    ISE_Territory NVARCHAR(43)
                    );
```

Rather than doing multiple insert into statements have only 1:

```
    INSERT INTO #PILOTTERR 
    VALUES (N'00544','NY04',N'Long Island',N'New York-Long Island',N'US Northeast',N'SE-New York/Long Island-A',N'ISE-New York/Long Island-D'),
           (N'01001','MA01',N'North Boston',N'North Boston',N'US Northeast',N'SE-North Boston-C',N'ISE-North Boston-B'),
         (etc..)
```

And if your datatype is NVARCHAR then begin the quotes with N'' thsi way the server does not have to do the conversion from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR.

And replace TEXT with a much smaller sensible datatype such as  NVARCHAR(10) which I think should suffice for a ZIPCODE

Better yet as I mentioned in my comment if you are sourcing your data from a excel or csv you can use SQL Server's Import data Wizard. You can find out more about it [HERE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/)

Comment: I tried doing this but I get this error :  "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','. "  Is there a different way to do this for SQL Server 2012?  Every where I've look it gives your solution, but that isn't working for me.  I even had my tech savvy friend look at it and they don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried a simplier table as well.            Create Table #Number (One int);         Insert Into #Number (One)          Values    (1),(2)                         This returned the same error

Comment: are you running the insert INSERT INTO #PILOTTERR 
    VALUES (N'00544','NY04',N'Long Island',N'New York-Long Island',N'US Northeast',N'SE-New York/Long Island-A',N'ISE-New York/Long Island-D'),
           (N'01001','MA01',N'North Boston',N'North Boston',N'US Northeast',N'SE-North Boston-C',N'ISE-North Boston-B')

Comment: or are you running it like INSERT INTO #PILOTTERR 
    VALUES (N'00544','NY04',N'Long Island',N'New York-Long Island',N'US Northeast',N'SE-New York/Long Island-A',N'ISE-New York/Long Island-D'),
           (N'01001','MA01',N'North Boston',N'North Boston',N'US Northeast',N'SE-North Boston-C',N'ISE-North Boston-B'),
         (etc..)

Comment: Yes, I even copy and pasted your comment into SQL and I still get this error.  Could there be something in the Settings that isn't allowing me to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm running the first way you mentioned.